# Have Annotation Processor Ignore files based on gradle flag

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I have two gradle projects (A, B)
And they use the same annotation processor the problem is that A has exactly one part of the processor it does not need.

Is there a way to configure gradle so that the annotation processor performs differently for A vs B?

I would not like to make two annotation processors since they are identical except for one tiny part.  (think like 2-3 lines of code)

Comment: Are you in control of this annotation processor? If so, you could have it accept options which changes its behavior.

Comment: I am in controller of the processor.
How do I have gradle pass these options?

Comment: I figured this out @Slaw if you want to create an answer I can mark it as solved otherwise I will just create an answer myself :)

Comment: Feel free to post your own solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell about gradle, but in maven you can pass compile time arguments in the following way

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>org.rapster.xxx.xxx.xxComponentProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
                <compilerArgs>
                   <arg>-Awidget=something</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This compile time argument can be read in your annotation processor by the following snippet in init function of processor

```
this.widget = processingEnv.getOptions().get("widget");
```

You can use this property to do certain conditional action.

Same can be done via gradle, I believe